# EKEditviewController keeps showing the title in the navigationbar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, eventkit, ekeventkit

I'm working with the `EventKit Framework`. It is working almost perfect but I have still some issues. When I push my on an Event, it goes to the details of that Event. It shows correctly the details and I can also edit and save it. The problem is with the navigation bar.

It shows the titles inside the navigation bar.These titles are *Event Details and Edit*. Also it is not showing a backbutton, to go back to my calendar. What I also should mention is that I'm using the Kal Calendar framework.

I'm pushing to de detailsViewController like this.

```
 Appointment *appointment = [dataSource appointmentAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Upon selecting an event, create an EKEventViewController to display the event.
    self.detailViewController = [[EKEventViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.detailViewController.title = @"";
    detailViewController.event = appointment.event;

    // Allow event editing.
    detailViewController.allowsEditing = YES;

   [calendar.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

And this is how my delegate looks like

```
// Overriding EKEventEditViewDelegate method to update event store according to user actions.
- (void)eventEditViewController:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller
          didCompleteWithAction:(EKEventEditViewAction)action {

    NSError *error = nil;
    EKEvent *thisEvent = controller.event;
    controller.title = @"";
    switch (action) {
        case EKEventEditViewActionCanceled:
            // Edit action canceled, do nothing.
            break;

        case EKEventEditViewActionSaved:
            // When user hit "Done" button, save the newly created event to the event store,
            // and reload table view.
            // If the new event is being added to the default calendar, then update its
            // eventsList.
            if (self.defaultCalendar ==  thisEvent.calendar) {
                [self.eventsList addObject:thisEvent];
            }
            [controller.eventStore saveEvent:controller.event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
            //[calendar reloadData];
            break;

        case EKEventEditViewActionDeleted:
            // When deleting an event, remove the event from the event store,
            // and reload table view.
            // If deleting an event from the currenly default calendar, then update its
            // eventsList.
            if (self.defaultCalendar ==  thisEvent.calendar) {
                [self.eventsList removeObject:thisEvent];
            }
            [controller.eventStore removeEvent:thisEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
            //[calendar reloadData];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    // Dismiss the modal view controller
    [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


// Set the calendar edited by EKEventEditViewController to our chosen calendar - the default calendar.
- (EKCalendar *)eventEditViewControllerDefaultCalendarForNewEvents:(EKEventEditViewController *)controller {
    EKCalendar *calendarForEdit = self.defaultCalendar;
    return calendarForEdit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you have added navigation item on the storyboard or nib file. remove it.

make `self.title=nil;` or `self.title=@"";`

Comment: I can't remove it. I think this is because I've embeded in a navigation controller.

Comment: @StefGeelen:why you cant remove it

Comment: Because once you embed your VC into a navigation controller. It automatically adds it to your VC.

Comment: if u have externally added then you can remove it.if u not added externally then it not requires

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```
EKEventEditViewController * controller = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
    controller.eventStore = self.eventStore;
    controller.event = result;
    controller.title = @"";
    controller.navigationItem.title = @"";
    controller.navigationItem.titleView = [UIView new];
    NSArray * array =controller.navigationBar.items;
    UINavigationItem * titleItem = array.firstObject;
    titleItem.title = @"";
    controller.editViewDelegate = (id)self;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

The `EKEventEditViewController` is not embedded in a navigation controller, it has its own `UINavigationBar`, I keep the navigation item if Apple will change this in the future and embed it in a navigation controller.